# android:layout_weight considers size of an embedded ImageViewer in a FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So my main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:weightSum="1">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:background="#597eAA">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#7ba1d1"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_conekta"/>

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bodyLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:background="#f3f3f3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/footerFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:background="#597eAA" >
</FrameLayout>
```

What I was trying to accomplish was to have the screen split up into three: a header and footer of equal height and a body of the remaining.

When I run this code, the headerFrameLayout ends up being the size of the footerFrameLayout+the height of the logoImage. For example: headerFrameLayout=163, logoImage=58, footerFrameLayout=105 and the bodyLinearLayout=493.

I don't understand why the header also considers the size of the photo. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not obvious, but that's just how it works. If you want a 15%, 70%, 15% distribution set each of those elements to have a height of `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:weightSum="1">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:background="#597eAA">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#7ba1d1"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_conekta"/>

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bodyLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:background="#f3f3f3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/footerFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:background="#597eAA" >
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```